# What is going on with JavaScript scope here?

Tags: javascript, scope

I've written the following snippet of code:

```
var f = function() { document.write("a"); };

function foo() {
    f();

    var f = function() { document.write("b"); };
}

foo();
```

I expected the function that prints `a` to be called, but it instead gives a runtime error about calling an `undefined` value. Why does this happen?

Comment: This phenomenon is certainly detailed in every beginner JavaScript book, not to mention countless beginner tutorials and StackOverflow questions. Hard to understand why people still get stuck on this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's about variables hoisting http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html , http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/

You code is eqvivalent to the next one;

```
var f = function() { document.write("a"); };
function foo() {
    //all var statements are analyzed when we enter the function
    var f;
    //at this step of execution f is undefined;
    f();
    f = function() { document.write("b"); };
}
foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since (just like in java) you don't have to worry about the order you define things in in a file a certain situation occurs. When you redefine the variable f it blanks out the other version of f but it is not defined until after so when f is called you get an error.